# Code of model created by EMF is not compiled

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, xtext, tycho, emf

I observed the following problem.
I support an application that is based on [XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) framework. The maven build was selected as primary build system. Tycho plugin is used for this. I would like to add to my application one more plugin that contains a domain model. It was decided to use EMF for this purposes. The code that created by EMF is not compiled due  to a lot lost references and collides in generated code. For example :

```
 C:\Users\agorlov\workspaces\flexprod\atom\FXPST-19474-implementation\implementation\com.psl.atom.parent\com.psl.atom.flexprod.model.FirstmileModel\src\com\psl\atom\flexprod\model\firstmile\FirstmilePackage.java:[3]
[ERROR] package com.psl.atom.flexprod.model.firstmile;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The package com.psl.atom.flexprod.model.firstmile collides with a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\agorlov\workspaces\flexprod\atom\FXPST-19474-implementation\implementation\com.psl.atom.parent\com.psl.atom.flexprod.model.FirstmileModel\src\com\psl\atom\flexprod\model\firstmile\FirstmilePackage.java:[11]
[ERROR] import com.psl.atom.flexprod.model.firstmile.impl.FirstmilePackageImpl;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I looked in code and see that : Interface refers to its implementation

```
FirstmilePackage eINSTANCE = com.psl.atom.flexprod.model.firstmile.impl.FirstmilePackageImpl.init();
```

Seems to me this is strange. Compiler says that there is that there is collides between interface definition and its implementation. How can I make generated code correct?

Comment: could you share sample code of what you are doing

Comment: Do you mean generated code?

Comment: No I mean something that allows me to reproduce eg a git repo with  sample checked in

Comment: I think the issue can be reproduced by the following way.  Create xtext project (hello world). Select maven as builder. Add to this project one more EMF model

Comment: Then please share this code as I can’t reproduce it